# Xamarin Forms Get Object element on image click

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a CollectionView from a List called: `List<Set> Sets` and in a Set I have a List called `List<Picture> Pictures`.

Here is what the classes look like:

```
public class Set
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Picture> Pictures{ get; set; }
}
```

And the picture class looks like this:

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my XAML I added a click event on every image, because I need to know which image has been clicked. The problem is that I also need to know in which set the image click has been done, because an image can be in multiple sets.

Here is the XAML:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Sets}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ff:CachedImage Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding imageSource}">
                                <ff:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="AlbumFoto_Clicked" />
                                </ff:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                            </ff:CachedImage>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Now I already got this code:

```
private void AlbumFoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CachedImage image = (CachedImage)sender;
    var setPicture = image.Source.BindingContext as Picture;
    var ImageId = setPicture.Id;

    var Pictureindex = 0;
    foreach (var set in Sets.Where(set => Pictures.Picture.Any(p => p.Id == ImageId)))
    {
        Pictureindex = set.Pictures.Picture.FindIndex(p => p.Id == ImageId);
    }
}
```

Now how can I get the Id from the set of clicked image?

Comment: Are you using MVVM?

Comment: Yes I am using a ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an click event, you should use `Command` and `CommandParameter` and use the BindingContext of the parent Collection

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Sets}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollView x:Name="ParentCollection" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ff:CachedImage Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding imageSource}">
                                <ff:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ImageClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding BindingContext.Id, Source={x:Reference Name=ParentCollection}}"/>
                                </ff:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                             </ff:CachedImage>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

And in your ViewModel:

```
public Command<int> ImageClickCommand{ get; set; }
```

And in your ViewModel Constructor:

```
ImageClickCommand = new Command<int>((Id) =>
{
    //Id -> id of the image
});
```

But if you still want to use the Clicked Event, i would sugest you do this change.

Add a new property to your Picture Class:

```
public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SetId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming that you receive that Collection from a Service, you could iterate over it and set your SetId like this:

```
foreach (var item in Collection)
{
    foreach (var picture in item.Pictures)
    {
         picture.SetId = item.Id   
    }         
}
```

Now in your Clicked you should have access to both Picture Id and the respetive Set Id:

```
private void AlbumFoto_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CachedImage image = (CachedImage)sender;
    var setPicture = image.Source.BindingContext as Picture;
    var ImageId = setPicture.Id;
    var SetId = setPicture.SetId;
    //...
}
```

Comment: I need the Set Id, not Image Id.... In my question is already the code to get the ImageId!

Comment: Then I have another question with you code... If I use it your way, how can I get both the Picture Id and the Set Id? So in the ViewModel after I click on the picture, I want the Picture Id and the Id from the Set where the picture is in!

Comment: hm... maybe add a property to your Picture class like int SetId, then that way, you can use the event you already have, and in the sender you would have acess to the picture id and set id

Comment: I don't quite get it, could you please give me an example code or something. I understand the first part, but now with the sender!?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk i don't know how are you fetching your data, but i will add something to my anwser (i will supose that you receive your collection from a API service)

Comment: Yes indeed! I get my data from a webcall and receive XML that I parse to those classes

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk check it and see if it helps